# How to initialise a field in ABSTRACT CLASS by using constructor

Tags: java, constructor, get, set, abstract-class

I have abstract class Human and many child classes(over 10). All i need is to set value to field "famName". It is a sum of field "name" and "surname"("name" + " " + "surname"). It looks like

**Abstract class**

```
public abstract class Human{

private String name;

private String fam;

//Setters and Getters

/*
private String famName = this.getName() + this.getFam();

*/

public Human(fam,name){
this.fam = fam;
this.name = name;
this.famName = this.fam + " " + this.name;

}


}
```

**Entity class**

```
public class Policeman extends Human{

//fields

}
```

So, the question is "how to inititalise this field famName" in abstract class, avoiding to use it in constructor in child classes? Thanks

Comment: What do you think is wrong with `public Human(fam,name)` ?

Comment: *how to inititalise this field famName* - make a getter method

Comment: I think, there is also a problem in your Constructor... it should be public Human(String fam, String name)...

Answer (score 0):

According to your question...look at this.

**Your abstract class:**

```
public abstract class Human {
    private String name;
    private String fam;
    private String famName;


    public Human(String fam, String name) {
        this.fam = fam;
        this.name = name;
        this.famName = this.fam + " " + this.name;

    }

    public String getFamName() {
        return famName;
    }

}
```

**Entity class:**

here you call the super constructor (from Human Class) in Policeman Constructor.

```
public class Policeman extends Human {

    public Policeman(String fam, String name) {
        super(fam, name);
    }
}
```

**Possible use:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Policeman policeman = new Policeman("Doe", "John");

    policeman.getFamName();

}
```

> In this case, you don't need to use abstract for the Human Class. You can use SuperClass and SubClass. The subClasses inherit then
>   from SuperClass.